# Docker: Can we reuse a layer of an image for building another image

Tags: docker

I have already created an image locally and it contains two layers

```
$ docker images inspect existingimagename

"RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:e21695bdc8e8432b1a119d610d5f8497e2509a7d040ad778b684bbccd067099f",
                "sha256:3ff73e68714cf1e9ba79b30389f4085b6e31b7a497f986c7d758be51595364de"
            ]
        },
```

Now i am building another image and want to save space. The first layer of the previous image is the main file system. So i decided to use it

```
FROM  sha256:e21695bdc8e8432b1a119d610d5f8497e2509a7d040ad778b684bbccd067099f
ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8
CMD ["/usr/bin/bash"]
```

Then i try to build the new image

```
$ docker build -t newimage -f Dockerfile .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  443.5MB
Step 1/3 : FROM sha256:e21695bdc8e8432b1a119d610d5f8497e2509a7d040ad778b684bbccd067099f
pull access denied for sha256, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

it gives error.

So how to deal with this.

Comment: `ADD` command has different purpose, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add for more details. For referencing layers you have to use `FROM` instruction. Can you add `Dockerfile` of `existingimagename` and describe what exactly do you want to reuse?

Comment: I modified the question. Added the sha256 to FROM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to profit from image layer cache is to create a base image with just the first layer.

Then use `FROM <base image>` in your other Dockerfiles.

This way, disk space will be spared as multiple images will share the same layer and also builds will be faster.

**Dockerfile-base:**

```
FROM scratch
ADD ./system.tar.gz /
```

```sh
docker build -f Dockerfile-base -t base .
```

---

**Dockerfile-1:**

```
FROM base
COPY ./somefiles /
```

```sh
docker build -f Dockerfile-1 -t image1 .
```

---

**Dockerfile-2:**

```
FROM base
COPY ./otherfiles /
```

```sh
docker build -f Dockerfile-2 -t image2 .
```

---

### Recommended reads

[Best practices for writing Dockerfiles § Leverage build cache](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache)

Comment: Yes thats the only way  i think. But i have already created an image. So for this purpose i have to again create any image. If i were pulling from repo then its no extra space is used. Here i have to create an first layered fresh again

Comment: If you take the exact first lines of your first Dockerfile and just remove lines from the bottom, then when building that image docker will be clever and reuse already existing layers. It should go fast. Just keep the top of the Dockerfile identicals